# Showing Boundedness of Linear Operator on Schwartz Space

Tags: harmonic-analysis, schwartz-space

In class, my professor said that for $\mu \in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n), p \in [1,\infty]$, we have a bounded linear operator $\mu':\mathcal{S(\mathbb{R}^n)} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $\mu'(\phi):= \int \mu(x)\phi(x)dx$.

It is easy to see this is a linear operator, but how can I prove it's bounded? In particular, we'd then want to show $\exists M>0$ such that $\forall \phi \in \mathcal{S(\mathbb{R}^n)},$

$$ |\mu'(\phi)|= |\int \mu(x)\phi(x)dx| \leq M||\phi(x)||_{\mathcal{S(\mathbb{R}^n)}}$$
However, my question is:

a) How does $\mu \in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n), p \in [1,\infty]$ help here?

b) Since the Schwartz class comes with a countable collection of semi-norms, rather than a single norm, how can we make sense of $||\phi(x)||_{\mathcal{S(\mathbb{R}^n)}}$, and thus the bounding condition above?

Comment: It should be said continuous, not bounded. Even if it is bounded for some of the semi-norms ($\mu  = \mu 1_{|\mu|\le1}+ \mu 1_{|\mu|>1}$  where $ \mu 1_{|\mu|>1}$ is $L^1$)

Comment: What is the norm in $S(\mathbb R^{n})$?

Comment: I am also not sure @geetha290krm - that is my second question.

Comment: We have $S(\mathbb{R}^n)\subset L^q(\mathbb{R}^n)$ where $q$ is the dual exponent  Hence the operator is indeed bounded, continuous in particular.